# Assigning sql varchar to JLabel value

Tags: java, sql, swing, jlabel, resultset

I've been assigning `varchar` values from a SQL database to jLabels in Java.

The length of the label is the maximum length the varchar could be in the database. When I open the window, label text is  much further apart than it should be.

Is there any way to avoid this?

Answer (score 1):

i don't think varchar/char matters here.why don't you use a trim on the field and see if this goes away?

i.e

```
select trim(my_field) from my_table where .....
```